# ¿Despliegue de una servidor realizada en java-helidon-microprofile?

Tags: java, heroku

Estoy realizado un servidor en java con Helidon  y necesito  desplegar en heroku. https://helidon.io/docs/latest/#/se/guides/26_gradle_build

No encontrado nada en la documentación como realizarlo, si tiene algúna guía me pueden ayudar, por favor.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files, estado pensando en irme por este lado, tengo estos ejecutables
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de generar los ejecutables y probar en la consola de windows funciona, pero al cargar en herokus me sale el error de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: haz usado github? hay un tema que es hooks,y heroku es capaz de enlazar con github para hacer deployments

Comment: Si usado github, ayer intente con los archivos jar y me salio estos errores

Comment: por fa edita la pregunta y agrega los logs

Comment: Si usado github, ayer intente con los archivos jar y se carco correstamente como dice la documentación, pero me salio estos errores: Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail                 comando: heroku deploy:jar servidor01-all.jar  --app helidon, ejecuto el comando y me sale esto logs --tail: Error: Missing required flag:  -a, --app APP  app to run command against,  See more help with --help. Gracias.